# IntelliJIdea terminal falling and closing

Tags: intellij-idea, logging, jboss, console-application, intellij-idea-2020

I have set the terminal in IntelliJIdea to no shell integration, no close session when it ends. (I tried to change them, but that did not help against the current problem)

2020.1 was installed, and after that, when I launch the JBoss AS 6.1 in the IntelliJIdea terminal (C:\Java\Servers\jboss-6.1.0\bin\run.bat), after some output the terminal falls, cleaning the content of the terminal's tab and printing to the IntelliJIdea's log:

```
2020-04-14 15:07:08,804 [12688536]  ERROR - iterm.terminal.TerminalStarter - Caught exception in terminal thread 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while applying com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.build.output.GenericFileFilter@2c5875ce to 'jboss---15:07:08,777 WARN  [CacheManager] Creating a new instance of CacheManager using the diskStorePath "C:\Users\GANGN_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\" which is already used by an existing CacheManager.'
```

Notice, IDE is not building anything at that moment and the product opened in the IDE is not run by Gradle, but by Maven.

Do you know about how I can manage that error, except downgrading the IntelliJIdea.

Changes in settings of shell integration and "close session when it ends" do not change anything. The same launch from without the IDE runs OK.

Comment: Does it help to disable "Android" plugin?

Comment: Yes, it helped! Excellent! Please, put that as an answer

Answer (score 3):

Please try to disable "Android" plugin.

Comment: Your advice works. Thank you very much. But that means that terminal WITH android plugin turned on does not work? And what if I want to code for Android?